# Can I increase the zoom of Widowmaker's sniper rifle?

Tags: overwatch

Sometimes at certain ranges the scope is far too short to see anything. Using scroll wheel, like in some games, doesn't let me toggle the zoom at all. Is there a way to increase the zoom on her scope or is the zoom by default the only zoom there is?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As of now (May 10, 2016), Widowmaker's zoom level is fixed. You cannot increase or decrease her zoom level.